# Bootstrap 3 carousel showing but not working/sliding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm trying to use a BS carousel, I made a [test page here](http://www.pscompetitiveedge.com/leadership-carousel.html). I see it but it's not moving/sliding. I searched in here and on Google. This is my first ever attempt at a carousel. I used to use a pure css slider but it wouldn't fit for what I need for my friend's page. 
I can't figure out what is wrong. Thanks in advance.

```css
<!--custom css in custom.css page-->

.carousel-control {
  padding-top:10%;
  width:5%;
}
.carousel-inner > .item.prev,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Peter Scotts Competitive Edge</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a0aac8df13.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#openBtn').click(function(){
 $('#myModal').modal({show:true})
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-navigation-container navbar-fixed-top" id="primary-navbar">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Mobile Toggle Button and stuff -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#primary-navigation" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            Menu <i style="font-size:24px" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
                        </button>
           <a href="#" class="pull-left navbar-brand"><img src="images/Brand.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Peter Scott's Competitive Edge"></a> 
                          </div>
       <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <!-- End of mobile toggle button -->
                    <!-- Start of the navbar -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="primary-navigation">
                        <ul class="nav  nav-justified">
                            <li><a href="index.html"><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa fa-home"></i> Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="programs.html"><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa fa-fire"></i> Programs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="references.html"><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa fa-group"></i> References</a></li>
                            <li><a href="rates.html"><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa fa-usd"></i> Rates</a></li>
                            <li><a href="faq.html"><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa fa-question"></i> FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html"><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
</div>  
<header class="masthead">
      <img src="images/Banner.jpg" class="center-block img-responsive" alt="logo">
</header>     
<!-- /.container -->
<!-- Feature -->
<div class="container">
<h1>Develop More Effective Leaders With The Leadership Team Challenge</h1> 
<img src="images/STEP-UP.gif" class="center-block img-responsive" alt="Step Up">
<div class="well">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="slide/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="teamwork"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="slide/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="fire eating"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="slide/3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="fire walk"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x"><img src="slide/4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="trust fall"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    
<!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="slide/5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="trust fall 2"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="slide/6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="crew"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="slide/7.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="fire eating 2"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="slide/8.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="fire eating 3"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <!--/carousel-inner--> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
 </div>
 <!--/myCarousel-->
        </div>
</div>
<div class="scroll-top-wrapper ">
 <span class="scroll-top-inner">
  <i class="fa fa-2x fa-arrow-circle-up"></i>
 </span>
</div>
<footer>    
<!-- Copyright etc -->
<div id="footer">
<p>Copyright &copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> Peter Scott's Competitive Edge</p>
</div>
</footer>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.bootstrap-dropdown-hover.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport bug workaround -->
<script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
<script>
      //$('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').bootstrapDropdownHover();
      $.fn.bootstrapDropdownHover();
      //$('#dropdownMenu1').bootstrapDropdownHover();
      //$('.navbar [data-toggle="dropdown"]').bootstrapDropdownHover();
    </script>    
    <script>
      // demo for realtime configuration and destroy
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({container: 'body'});

      $('#setSticky').on('click', function () {
        $('.setdemo [data-toggle="dropdown"]').bootstrapDropdownHover('setClickBehavior', 'sticky');
      });

      $('#setDefault').on('click', function () {
        $('.setdemo [data-toggle="dropdown"]').bootstrapDropdownHover('setClickBehavior', 'default');
      });

      $('#setDisable').on('click', function () {
        $('.setdemo [data-toggle="dropdown"]').bootstrapDropdownHover('setClickBehavior', 'disable');
      });

      $('#set1000').on('click', function () {
        $('.setdemo [data-toggle="dropdown"]').bootstrapDropdownHover('setHideTimeout', 1000);
      });

      $('#set200').on('click', function () {
        $('.setdemo [data-toggle="dropdown"]').bootstrapDropdownHover('setHideTimeout', 200);
      });

      $('#destroy').on('click', function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
        $('.setdemo [data-toggle="dropdown"]').bootstrapDropdownHover('destroy');
        $('#destroy, #set200, #set1000, #setDisable, #setDefault, #setSticky').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#reinitialize').prop('disabled', false);
        $('.setdemo').addClass('destroyed');
      });

      $('#reinitialize').on('click', function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
        $('.setdemo [data-toggle="dropdown"]').bootstrapDropdownHover();
        $('#destroy, #set200, #set1000, #setDisable, #setDefault, #setSticky').prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('.setdemo').removeClass('destroyed');
      });
    </script>
<script> 
$(function(){
 
 $(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
 
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
   $('.scroll-top-wrapper').addClass('show');
  } else {
   $('.scroll-top-wrapper').removeClass('show');
  }
 });
});
</script>
<script>
 $(function(){
 
 $(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
 
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
   $('.scroll-top-wrapper').addClass('show');
  } else {
   $('.scroll-top-wrapper').removeClass('show');
  }
 });
 
 $('.scroll-top-wrapper').on('click', scrollToTop);
});
 
function scrollToTop() {
 verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
 element = $('body');
 offset = element.offset();
 offsetTop = offset.top;
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: offsetTop}, 500, 'linear');
}
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#myCarousel').carousel({
 interval: 10000
 })
    
    $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
     //alert("slid");
 });
    
    
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to the bottom of the code and it works.

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```